# mysql inner join construct with distict columns

Tags: mysql, inner-join, distinct

I have a problem to fetch records from 4 different tables classroom_students, students, courses and result
the query is to

1. fetch all students (matric_no only) in the classroom_students with the (class, department and session)
2. With each selected matric_no get the students details from the student table
3. Get the scores of the selected matric_no from result table
4. Get corresponding course_code of the selected score in step 3 above
5. Repeat step 2 to 4 for each selected matric_no in step 1

**Classroom_students**

```
    id        ||  int
    class_id  ||  int   
    dept_id   ||  int
    matric_no ||  varchar(30)
    session   ||  int
```

**students**

```
    id            ||  int
    sname         ||  varchar(30)
    fname         ||  varchar(30)
    mname         ||  varchar(30)
    matric_no     ||  varchar(30)
    year_of_entry ||  int
    status        ||  varchar(30)
    dept          ||  int
    level         ||  int
```

**result**

```
    result_id     ||  int
    matric_no     ||  int
    course_id     ||  int
    score         ||  int
    semester      ||  int
    level         ||  int
    session       ||  int
```

**courses**

```
    course_id         || int
    course_code       ||  varchar(30)
    course_title      ||  varchar(30)
    course_unit       ||  varchar(30)
    semester          ||  int
    level             ||  int
    dept              ||  int
```

I have tried the following code but only returned the details in the student details and classroom_students leaving the courses and result table records

```
    $get_student = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT CONCAT(st.sname,' 
    ',st.fname,' ',st.mname) as sName, cls.matric_no, rs.score, 
    rs.course_id, 
    cs.course_code, cs.course_title, cs.course_unit FROM student AS st
    INNER JOIN classroom_students AS cls
    ON cls.matric_no = st.matric_no
    INNER JOIN result AS rs
    ON rs.matric_no = cls.matric_no
    INNER JOIN courses AS cs
    ON cs.course_id = rs.course_id
    WHERE rs.course_id = cs.course_id
    AND rs.semester = '$semester'
    AND rs.level = '$level'
    AND rs.session = '$session'
    ") or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));
```

I want to implement the above task using inner join. Any help will really be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: This is simplest inner join. try it and still if u see any issues let us know.

Comment: Read & act on [mcve].